# Bind a collection to Ninject

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, collections, ninject

While developing a WPF application with Ninject I analyzed there are some collections that should exist only once in the code.

For example, the Main Window consists of a inner list of project tabs, something like tabs in a browser. The main window's view model contains this property `ObservableCollection<ProjectViewModel>` ...and my idea was like, hey, there is one and ONLY one ObservableCollection of ProjectViewModel. What happens if I bind such type as a singleton with Ninject?

So I wrote something like this...

```
if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic) //pure WPF design mode check looks
                                        //differently (this is MVVM Light)
{
    kernel.Bind<ObservableCollection<Project>>().ToMethod((c) =>
    {
        return new ObservableCollection<Project>() { new Project("Lorem", "Ipsum") }; 
    }
} 
else 
{
    kernel.Bind<ObservableCollection<Project>>()
          //.ToSelf() <-- ToSelf() does not work
          .ToMethod((c) => 
          {
              return new ObservableCollection<Project>();
          }).InSingletonScope();
}
```

And it WORKS! In design mode, I actually see "Lorem" and "Ipsum" and while running, the code seems to work as expected, with the collection in the main view model being empty. And the code looks pretty nice and readable.

But I'm being sceptical and suspicous, I feel I'm doing something really dirty and bad since I could not find any example of a similar code where a type of a collection of classes is bound to a certain implementation. But I might not have been searching enough.

Is binding a collection of some classes good idea in Ninject? Could that cause any unexpected problems?

Comment: `IsInDesignModeStatic` huh?  *Static?* You didn't just actually put the word "Static" in a static method name to indicate that it was static, did you?

Comment: That's MVVM Light property

Comment: Eeew. I mean, seriously, eew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really feel like that's too dirty. This is all kept in the bootstrapper, so it's easy to go look there and see what the behavior is. You're shoving all of the control state under the carpet to keep things clean in the other parts of your code.